Problema ao executar VBA no script R <checkErrorInfo> -2147352567
Eu tenho uma planilha xlsm (VBA) com o seguinte código macro:
Private Sub Atualizar_Click()

'Parametros a serem informados
Dim Raiz As String
Dim Moeda As String
Dim Data_Ini As String
Dim Data_Fim As String

resposta = MsgBox("Durante a atualização, o Excel ficará 
indisponível." & Chr(13) & "Este processo pode demorar." & 
Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Deseja continuar ?", vbQuestion + 
vbYesNo, "Confirma Carga")

'Atribui a Variável, o conteúdo das Células
Data_Ini = Sheets("Base").Range("G5").Value
Data_Fim = Sheets("Base").Range("G6").Value
Raiz = Sheets("Base").Range("G7").Value
Moeda = Sheets("Base").Range("G8").Value

'Passa os parametros para a StoredProcedure
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Integracoes").OLEDBConnection
.CommandText = "EXEC EXT_CRE028_Carteira_Credito "
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Integracoes").Refresh

no script R estou tentando rodar o seguinte:
library(xlsxjars)
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)
library(RDCOMClient)

fn <- "C:/Users/MyUser/OneDrive - My/Área de Trabalho/Extracoes/CRE028 - Carteira do Crédito.xlsm"
MacroPath = "Atualizar_Click"

excelApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")

xlWbk <- excelApp$Workbooks()$Open(fn)

Sys.sleep(1)
excelApp$Run(MacroPath) 

Ele abre o arquivo CRE028 - Carteira do Crédito.xlsm mas na hora de executar dá o seguinte erro:
 <checkErrorInfo> -2147352567 
 Erro: Exceção.

Meu Rtools 4.4
  > sessionInfo()
  R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
  Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
  Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

 Matrix products: default


 locale:
 [1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8 
 [2] LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8   
 [3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8
 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                      
 [5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8    

 time zone: Etc/GMT+3
 tzcode source: internal


Não duplique perguntas. Se precisar revisar algo faça na pergunta original clicando no link "editar" que fica abaixo da pergunta original. Comentários devem ser feitos na pergunta original, também.
